# Have you got a CascadingDropDown working with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, controls

If so how?

Did you roll your own with jQuery or use the Microsoft AJAX toolkit?

Did you create a webservice or call an action?

---

**EDIT** : Please note that this question was asked before Microsoft announced that they were going to bundle jQuery in with VS/ASP.NET MVC.  I think there is less of a discussion around this topic now and the answer would now almost always be 'use jQuery'. IainMH 11th Feb 2009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery, action, return JSON.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/mike_nichols/archive/2008/05/25/jquery-cascade-cascading-values-from-forms.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've spent the past day or two getting @[Matt Hinze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735/have-you-got-a-cascadingdropdown-working-with-aspnet-mvc#40120) to work.  It works well.  jQuery is the prefferred method of doing AJAX in the forthcoming [ASP.NET MVC In Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/) book from Manning.  You can get a pdf of a free preview chapter on AJAX in MVC [here](http://www.manning.com/palermo/palermo_meapch9_sample.pdf).

However, [Stephen Walther](http://www.aspworkshops.com/) in his excellent [ASP.NET Tip series](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/tags/Tips/default.aspx) has just blogged about creating cascading dropdowns in [Tip #41](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/09/06/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

CascadingDropDown jQuery Plugin for ASP.NET MVC

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/20/cascadingdropdown-jquery-plugin-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.noma.li/2010/03/autopostback-and-cascading-drop-downs-in-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/