# Form with related groupboxes update based on selection

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I am developing an application in asp.net MVC2, but I suspect this functionality may need to include jQuery.

Lets say I am trying to develop a slightly more complex form.

I have a number of dropdownlists. Once a certain value is selected in the first dropdownlist, let's say, `Categories` - I want the second dropdownlist, let's say, `Items` to update based on the data. So `Categories` and `Items` are related, and when a certain category is selected, only a certain subset of `Items` should be shown (the related ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you need cascading dropdowns. 
This can be done in JQuery.

You can check [Have you got a CascadingDropDown working with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735/have-you-got-a-cascadingdropdown-working-with-asp-net-mvc)

[Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET)

also you should check this as well
[jquery-ascx-and-webmethods-not-seems-to-be-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704916/jquery-ascx-and-webmethods-not-seems-to-be-working)